# Retrofit: how fix "only one http method is allowed. found: get and get"?

Tags: android, retrofit

I have that structure for request.
Request getTransportByStation work perfectly.
But I get exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: TransportWebService.getTransportByRoute: Only one HTTP method is allowed. Found: GET and GET.`
I found solution only for POST and POST.

```
interface TransportWebService {
    @GET(QUERY_CATEGORY_TRANSPORT + "GetTransportByNextStation/{station}")
    Observable<ResponseRouteList> getTransportByStation(
            @Path("city") String city,
            @Path("station") String station,
            @Query("count") int count,
            @Query("userid") String userId
    );

    @GET(QUERY_CATEGORY_TRANSPORT + "GetTransportByRoute/{route}")
    Observable<ResponseRouteList> getTransportByRoute(
            @Path("city") String city,
            @Path("station") String route,
            @Query("count") int count,
            @Query("userid") String userId
    );

    @GET(QUERY_CATEGORY_TRANSPORT + "Time")
    Observable<Integer> getTime(
            @Path("city") String city
    );
}
```

**UPD:** Retrofit version 1.9.0
Init service like this

```
private static final TransportWebService SERVICE = Common.getRestAdapter()
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(new Gson())
            .build()
            .create(TransportWebService.class);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the second GET method, the second argument (@PATH("station")) should be @PATH("route").

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error  found: POST and POST, my issue was that I was missing a path parameter in my URL but I was sending it along with the request.

I was hitting the URL without last parameter.

> http:www.webtest.requestService/customerapp/{context}/{token}/services/{flightLegId}/

Actual URL was should be:

> http:www.webtest.requestService/customerapp/{context}/{token}/services/{flightLegId}/{flightLegExtId}/

Answer (score 1):

This may happen because of tiny mistake like if you are giving parameter like   instead of {id}.

Answer (score 1):

The error the "GET and GET" or "POST and POST" error is masking the root exception.  It seems the most common exception is that your argument in the  HTTP argument method does not match the argument in your Path parameter.

The `{id}` in `@GET("/objects/{id}")` must match `id` in `@Path("id")`.